# How can we specify the text size, type, density when creating bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, text-size, drawbitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap with text on it. but I'm having troubles in specifying the options for that text, like the size, type, smoothness.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap resultBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(384,384, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Text Color  
paint.setStrokeWidth(24); // Text Size      
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern

// some more settings...
canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
canvas.drawText("00: Some text", 300, 10, paint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with density was the size of the bitmap itself, while it's small, the printed texts cannot be smooth!
Text size:

```
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
```

density is the same problem like smoothing, so just make it bigger.

type:

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD, Typeface.BOLD));
```

color:

```
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

background color:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

These options are available in the paint that will be used to draw the text on the canvas. Check for yourself with the autocomplete on android studio. Note that the color will be the paints original color, so there's no `setTextColor` method available.
[image]